# DX: force:source:pull returns "no results found" immediately after "force:source:status" reports Remote Changed?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Spun up a new scratch org and pushed source that was just converted from MDAPI.  Logged into the org and activated a lightning home page that was part of the source push.  After which, `sfdx force:source:status` reported the remote change:

```
> sfdx force:source:status

=== Source Status                             
STATE           FULL NAME              TYPE       PROJECT PATH
──────────────  ─────────────────────  ─────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Remote Changed  Default_LEX_Home_Page  FlexiPage  force-app/main/default/flexipages/Default_LEX_Home_Page.flexipage-meta.xml
```

I then ran `force:source:pull`, which reports no results:

```
> sfdx force:source:pull

=== Pulled Source                                                                                  
No results found
```

I tried `pull -f` and even `status` again, everything reports "No results found".  It's as though the `status` check changed the local sync state.  I have confirmed that no local source changes were made; git reports "working tree clean".

Is this a known issue?  Should I avoid `force:source:status`? Any way to reset the local state so I can pull the change?

**UPDATE** I tried spinning up a new scratch org and trying again, activating the lightning home page, and immediately pulling changes; "No results found".  After repeated attempts, I can find no way to pull in the fact that a lightning home page is "active" for all users.  Perhaps that is the real issue?

Comment: Check your `.forceIgnore` - Despite the docs saying `:status` uses `.forceignore` I have found `:status` reports changes that are supposed to be ignored and the pull correctly ignores it resulting in this scenario

Comment: @Eric didn't think of that, but just checked... nothing in .forceIgnore that should affect it.

Comment: I have had this problem too and I am sure it is as you think - sfdx can't pull activation info down from a scratch org (or push it up to one either). I couldn't find any solution to it, and ended up having to add manual steps to my scratch org initialisation process for activating lightning home pages. It also applies to lightning record pages too.  I would be interested to see whether there are plans to solve this in the future.